# Issue with variable outside of block in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm basically trying to assign URL's to the `Content.link` cases which I'm loading from a file in a block further up (getWebData).

I know that part is working because I can see it in the log, but what I do not understand is why the values are not available to me in this block when I call via `self getWebData:^(NSArray *arrValue)`

In the example below, it works because I have manually set each one via the `NSString *WebsiteLink1 = @"http://link1";` but as soon as I comment that out, I get a `Use of undeclared identifier 'WebsiteLink1'`.

I do not understand why it isn't working.

```
- (IBAction)ShowContent:(id)sender
    {
        Content = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Content"];

        [self getWebData:^(NSArray *arrValue)
         {
         NSString *WebsiteLink1 = arrValue[0];
         NSString *WebsiteLink2 = arrValue[1];
         NSString *WebsiteLink3 = arrValue[2];
         }
     ];
    NSString *WebsiteLink1 = @"http://link1";
    NSString *WebsiteLink2 = @"http://link2";
    NSString *WebsiteLink3 = @"http://link3";

    switch ([sender tag])
    {
        case 1:
            Content.link = WebsiteLink1;
            break;
        case 2:
            Content.link = WebsiteLink2;
            break;
        case 3:
            Content.link = WebsiteLink3;
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    lastViewController = Content;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:Content animated:YES];
}
```

My understanding is that this is the part that should call the block getWebData and make the array varaibles available, but it isn't doing so (no errors show).

```
  [self getWebData:^(NSArray *arrValue)
             {
             NSString *WebsiteLink1 = arrValue[0];
             NSString *WebsiteLink2 = arrValue[1];
             NSString *WebsiteLink3 = arrValue[2];
             }
         ];
```

The code from getWebData is here:

```
typedef void(^CallbackBlock)(id value);

- (void)getWebData:(CallbackBlock)callback
{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration];
    NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webdata.dat"]];

    [[session dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        if (data != nil && !error)
        {
            NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Full WebLinks%@", string);
            NSArray *arrValue = [string componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
            NSMutableArray *arrInfo = [NSMutableArray array];
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                NSString *WebsiteLink1 = arrValue[0];
                NSLog(@"WebsiteLink1 : %@", WebsiteLink1);
                NSString *WebsiteLink2 = arrValue[1];
                NSLog(@"WebsiteLink2 : %@", WebsiteLink2);
                NSString *WebsiteLink3 = arrValue[2];
                NSLog(@"WebsiteLink3 : %@", WebsiteLink3);
            });
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
        }
    }] resume];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that these 3 variables declared here

```
NSString *WebsiteLink1 = arrValue[0];
NSString *WebsiteLink2 = arrValue[1];
NSString *WebsiteLink3 = arrValue[2];
```

are in the scope of the block meaning that you can't access any of them as they are not existing in the outer scrope (IBAction method scope )

so you may use completion handler or move all bottom code inside the block , beside part of your code (the one that call `getWebData`) is **asynchronous** so you should not run code like this as the switch code will run before even you get the data from the web call , A refactor would be like this

```
- (IBAction)ShowContent:(id)sender
{
    Content = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Content"];

    [self getWebData:^(NSArray *arrValue)
     {
        NSString *WebsiteLink1 = arrValue[0];
        NSString *WebsiteLink2 = arrValue[1];
        NSString *WebsiteLink3 = arrValue[2];

       switch ([sender tag])
       {
         case 1:
           Content.link = WebsiteLink1;
           break;
         case 2:
           Content.link = WebsiteLink2;
           break;
         case 3:
          Content.link = WebsiteLink3;
          break;

         default:
         break;
     }

      lastViewController = Content;
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       [self.navigationController pushViewController:Content animated:YES];
      });
    }
 ];

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Interestingly, I tried a similar thing to this earlier and had a similar result, which is that while there are now no errors and the code runs, the icons do not work now. The URLs are assigned to each button via the Content.link to load a webview and now the buttons are unresponsive. I can see that when you press them, they log the NSLog, but now the webview does not load.

Comment: Thank you again. I had just got somewhere before you answered in that the icons are now responsive, but fail to load the content in the webview. If I run your edit, I get a error `Use of undeclared identifier 'DispatchQueue'`

Comment: Thank you again for your help, much appreciated. That has removed the error, but the icons are not loading the URL's in the webview, I just get the loading image. I can see when the buttons are pressed, the URL's are displaying in the NSLog, but I do not think they are getting into the NSString as it looks like there is nothing to load. I'm really not sure what else to try!

Comment: Thank you again for your help, I ultimately resolved it by moving pretty much the whole block down to the other block and loaded the URL with the data in there.

Thanks for helping me out, pure determination got me there in the end!

Comment: I spoke too soon, now, for copying all (most) of the code down to the second block (IBAction) I now get this error : `-[UIView tag] must be used from main thread only`

Back to the drawing board!

Comment: any UI related component must be manipulated from main thread

Comment: Understood, but then how do I then dynamically assign the URL's from an external source if I cannot put the code to get the data inside that UI block? All I really need to do is load some data (URLS) from an external source and assign then to the icons in `Content.link = WebsiteLink1;`